# Printing 1D array using pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I want to print the data of array by using pointers so I try to save the address of array in the pointer. But the pointer doesn't print the data. I will print a second array as well later on so there are some extra variables declared.

Output:
[image: Output]

**Code**

```
//print 1D array and 2D array
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int Arr1[10];
int Arr2[10][10];
int i, j, n1, n2;
int (*p1)[10];
int (*p2)[10][10];

int main()
{
    printf("For the 1D Array: \n");
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    printf("Enter the data for the elements:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &Arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("Displaying Array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", Arr1[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\nDisplaying using pointer: \n");
    p1=Arr1;
    printf("1D Array is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        printf("Arr[%d] is %d\t", i, *(p1[i]));
        printf("\nAddress of %d th array is %u\n", i, p1[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Arr1` IS the address of the array! `printf("Arr[%d] is %d\t", i, *(Arr1+i))` works

Comment: You need the address `p1=&Arr1;` also to print use `printf("Arr[%d] is %d\t", i, (*p1)[i]);` and `printf("\nAddress of %d th array is %p\n", i, *p1+i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer `p1` is declared like

```
int (*p1)[10];
```

In this assignment statement

```
p1=Arr1;
```

the pointer is assigned with an expression of the type `int *` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator to pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

The pointer types of the operands are not compatible. So the compiler should issue a message.

You could either write

```
int (*p1)[10];

//...

p1 = &Arr1;
printf("1D Array is: \n");
for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
    printf("Arr[%d] is %d\t", i, ( *p1 )[i] );
    printf("\nAddress of %d th array is %p\n", i,( void * ) ( *p1 + i ) );
}
```

The expression with the subscript operator

```
( *p1 )[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( *p1 + i )
```

Or you could write

```
int *p1;

//...

p1 = Arr1;
printf("1D Array is: \n");
for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
    printf("Arr[%d] is %d\t", i, p1[i]);
    printf("\nAddress of %d th array is %p\n", i,( void * ) ( p1 + i));
}
```

I suppose that in the second call of `printf` you want to output the  address of each element of the array..

Comment: Okay, I see the mistake in the incompatibility of pointer types. Yes, I wanted to print the address of each element in the array. 
What is the purpose of using `( void * )` ?

Comment: @L127Bangtanned The argument of the conversion specifier p shall be a pointer of the type void *.